# KendoUI Menubar open on click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-menu

I have a KenoUI `MenuBar`.

Code as per bellow:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .Name("UserMenu")
    .Events()
    .Items(items =>
     {
         items.Add().Text("Organisation Name");

         items.Add().Text("User Fullname").Items(useritems =>
         {
             useritems.Add().Text("Option 1");
             useritems.Add().Text("Option 2");
             useritems.Add().Text("Option 3");                                
          });

      }));
```

Pretty simple menu with a sub menu under `User Fullname`. I want to change this menu bar so that it does not open `Option 1, 2, 3` sub menu when one hovers over `User Fullname`.

Only if you click on `User Fullname` should that sub menu open.

Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [openOnClick](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/menu#configuration-openOnClick) method. By default, this is false, so the menu's open on hover. Setting it to true allows menus to open only when you click on them.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("UserMenu")
                .OpenOnClick(true)
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    items.Add().Text("Organisation Name");

                    items.Add().Text("User Fullname").Items(useritems =>
                    {
                        useritems.Add().Text("Option 1");
                        useritems.Add().Text("Option 2");
                        useritems.Add().Text("Option 3");                                
                    });

                }));
```